# Appinventor FTP to Web Server

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am trying to create an FTP page in AppInventor so I can upload and download files from an Androidmobile device to my web server.

Going through the forums I have read about Appinventor not supporting it but it could be done via 3rd-party application that you can open via ActivityStarter. 
Is this true and is this really the only way?

I only ask again because I've read through some outdated posts. If anyone is aware of a certain solution (direct or indirect) your tips and suggestions would be most appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ai4a/qywgqA9S-ow/fm31kaLlWbYJ), there are these solutions to upload/download files to a web server:
1) [how to upload a file](http://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php) 
2) [how to download a file](http://puravidaapps.com/filedownload.php)

Comment: Hi Taifun! We've met before! Yes indeed your solution works perfectly. My apologies for all the confusion.

Comment: Say, how about a general file picker solution instead of just an image picker? Would you recommend Scott's solution? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/app-inventor-developers-library/Sc4a1wZHL-Q/discussion

Comment: There is no official general file picker available. Scott's solution seems to be a good choice.

Comment: a general file picker solution for App Inventor is now available here http://puravidaapps.com/pick.php